# Может ли быть массив свойством класса?

Tags: c#, массивы

Если может быть, то как на примере массива строк это все можно организовать?

Comment: Запомните, пожалуйста, что всякий раз, когда вам нужен массив строк или любого другого типа одномерный массив, то в 99% случаев вам на самом деле следует использовать типизированную коллекцию - в вашем случае `List<string>`

Comment: @Bulson не соглашусь с рекомендацией. 1. Массив тоже типизированная коллекция. 2. Зачем создавать `List` если не планируется изменять размер?

Comment: @FoggyFinder в этом обсуждении легко скатиться во флуд, на этот счет уже понаписаны целые "простыни" разного рода мнений, но по сути: массив в C# это наследие С, привычный подход для седовласых программеров пришедших из большого мира C&C++. Вот вы говорите, мол если не нужно изменять размер, то тогда почему бы не массив? А я вам отвечаю: а что в таком случае вы улучшаете по сравнению с использованием `List`? Пару свободных килобайт в памяти? Об этом можно было бы серьезно говорить в случае системного программирования, а не прикладного.

Comment: На всякий случай уточню, что `List<_>` по своей сути и есть массив, только с возможностью изменять размерность @Bulson Дело не в килобайтах, просто предпочитаю использовать инструмент под задачу: Если изменение размеров не планируется, емкость известна заранее, то будет достаточно использовать массив, а методы `List<_>` будут избыточны. Предмет спора - дело вкуса. Мой комментарий был всего лишь ответом и небольшим уточнением на ваше безапелляционное заявление - `когда вам нужен массив строк или любого другого типа одномерный массив, то в 99% случаев вам на самом деле ...`.

Comment: @FoggyFinder конечно вы вправе делать как вам сподручнее. Я же свой комментарий писал для новичка и потому он был подан в такой форме. К концу подходит 2016, скоро выйдет седьмая версия C#. А люди все еще продолжают учиться по книгам изданным 10 лет назад или учят других использовать Array, ArrayList, Backgroundworker, APM, WebClient, Thread и прочее, которое уже давно пора отправить на свалку истории развития C#. Это все нужно знать, если вы по найму подправляете костыли в каком-то бородатом проекте. А если вы пишите что-то новое, то следует уже использовать актуальные возможности языка.

Comment: @Bulson полностью согласен

Comment: @Bulson как же все любят выкидывать всё на свалку истории. А вы не думали  что каждый лишний уровень абстракции, там где это не нужно понижает производительность решения? Ну да, конечно, если машина пользователя не тянет вашу программу виноват пользователь (сарказм). Сколько лет языку Си? Он потерял свою актуальность? Тоже относится и к низкоуровневым классам C#. Относительно устаревших высокоуровневых классов, вы по большей части правы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как пример:

```
using System;

namespace Answer
{
    class Test
    {
        private string[] _stringArray = new string[2];
        public string[] StringArray { get { return _stringArray; } }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Test();

            test.StringArray[0] = "Hello";
            Console.Write(test.StringArray[0]);
            test.StringArray[1] = " World";
            Console.Write(test.StringArray[1]);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а как в блоке set свойства public string[] StringArray присваивать значения элементам массива?

Comment: @Draktharon http://pastebin.com/70GwpTyt пример в коменты не влезет, по ссылке реализацию скинул

Answer (score 1):

Малость добавлю от себя. Если вы пишете код в Visual Studio, то очень удобно пользоваться так называемыми снипетами. Для создания свойств существует несколько снипетов:

- наберите `prop` и дважды нажмите на клавишу `Tab` у вас появится заготовка свойства `public int MyProperty { get; set; }` между `int` и `MyProperty` можно переключаться с помощью все той же `Tab`. Так вот, когда вы воспользуетесь этим снипетом, то курсор у вас будет стоять в позиции  `int` сразу начинайте вводить `List<string>` после нажмите `Tab` и вы сможете дать нужное вам название свойству, чтобы закончить нажмите клавишу ввода.
- `propg` даст `public int MyProperty { get; private set; }`
- `propfull` даст

  ```
  private int myVar;

  public int MyProperty
  {
      get { return myVar; }
      set { myVar = value; }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] args { get { return new string[5]; }
    set { } }
```

как и для всего остального

Comment: а в блоке set как устанавливать значения?

Comment: так же 
        string[] args
        {
            get { return new string[5]; }
            set { value[0]; }
        }s

Comment: string test;
        string[] args
        {
            get { return new string[5]; }
            set { test = value[0] ; }
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace Answer
{
    class Test
    {
        private string[] _stringArray = new string[2];
        public string[] StringArray
        {
            get { return _stringArray; }
            set
            {
                //value = массив
                if (value.Length == _stringArray.Length) {
                    for (int index = 0; index < value.Length; index++) {
                        string element = value[index];
                        _stringArray[index] = element;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Test();

            test.StringArray = new string[] { "Abra", " Cadabra" };

            Console.Write(test.StringArray[0]);
            Console.Write(test.StringArray[1]);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

из комментария @Vladislav Khapin